# Define struct with minimum size

Tags: c++, struct

I want to define a struct, e.g. `type`, such that `sizeof(type)` is no less than some value.

**Motivation:**

I have a vector `std::vector<type>` and I will remove some elements from it. Also, I have saved the indexes of some elements to other places, thus I want just mark it as not used and reuse it in the future. This leads me to save the next available position as a list in erased positions. As a result, `sizeof(type)` should be no less than `sizeof(size_t)` and `type` should be properly aligned as well.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. `boost::variant<type, size_t>`

   This has two problems from my point of view. If I `use boost::get<type>`, the performance will decrease significantly. If I use `boost::apply_visitor`, the syntax would be weird and the performance also decreases according to my profile.
2. `union{type t; size_t s;}`

   This of course works except for two shortfalls. Firstly, the syntax to refer the member of `type` would be more messy. Secondly, I have to define constructor, copy constructor, etc. for this union.
3. Extend `type` by `char[sizeof(size_t) - sizeof(type)]`

   This almost fulfills my requirements. However, this risks of zero length array which is not supported by the c++ standard and possibly wrong alignment.

Since I won't use `type` as `size_t` often, I'd like to just ensure I can use `reinterpret_cast<size_t>` when needed.

**Complements**

After reading the comments, I think the best solution for my problem should be `boost::variant`. But I am still wondering is there a way to combine the benefits of solution 2 and 3, i.e.

a. I can access members of `type` without changes.

b. Get the guarantee that `reinterpret_cast<size_t>` works.

Comment: very nice formulated question. +1. But it seems to me that  the source of your problem is that you save the indexed for future use. I think that you should think to some alternative that doesn't involve this kind of shenanigans with some elements in the vector being the next valid index in vector.

Comment: @bolov I agree with you. I used unique_ptr<type> in vector and saved type*. But I prefer direct access of type. (It is not for production use) In fact, I think boost::variant is perhaps my final solution, but I am looking forward for better solutions.

Comment: Why do you imagine that there would be a performance cost with boost::variant?

Comment: @RichardHodges I am not imaging. It has, which I have confirmed.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, of course, i.e. gcc 4.9, -O2. I also have checked its source code and it should has overheads. Yet, I admit that there perhaps has no better solution.

Comment: I'm just wondering about the motivation for the motivation. The way you describe it, it looks as if you want to intermingle the concept of a 'free list' and an object store. I am wondering why.

Comment: @RichardHodges I am sorry, but I do't quite understand your comments. What I want to do is similar to memory allocation. Nevertheless, it is an interesting question itself, I think.

Comment: I think this begs the question, "why not just do memory allocation?" Stl containers already have the concept of custom allocators, in case new/delete is not sufficient for our needs.

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't think std::allocator is for this, i.e. it allocates memory for std::vector instead of single elements. Moreover, it has no help for the problem asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mitigate the concerns about solution 3 with something like:

```
struct data
{
  // ...
};

template<class T, bool> class pad_;
template<class T> class pad_<T, true> { char dummy[sizeof(T) - sizeof(data)]; };
template<class T> class pad_<T, false> {};

template<class T> using pad = pad_<T, (sizeof(T) > sizeof(data))>;

class type : public data, pad<size_t>
{
  // ...
};
```

This code:

- assumes [empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) so that `pad` could be completely optimized out from `type` layout when `sizeof(data) >= sizeof(size_t)`
- hasn't the risk of zero length array

Comment: This looks great. One last concern, is there alignment problems if used as size_t?

Comment: For alignment you should add a [`alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) specifier to the `type` definition (C++11) or try with [`union`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214632/alignment-guarantees-of-static-char-array). All of this is quite tricky and I'm not sure it is worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Though this being an interesting problem the design itself seams questionable.

1. When inserting a new element items marked unused are considered first before growing the vector. It means that the relative order of items is unpredictable. If that's being acceptable you could have just used a vector of (smart) pointers.

   Typically a vector is inefficient when removing items from the middle. Since the order doesn't matter it is possible to swap the element being removed with the last element and pop the last element.
2. All elements are of the same size; allocating them using a pool could be faster then using the system allocator.

   A pool basically allocates memory in big chunks and hands out smaller chunks on request. A pool  usually stores the free list in yet unallocated chunks to track available memory (the same very idea described in the question). There are some good implementations readily available (from Boost and other sources).
3. Concerning the original design it is cumbersome to enumerate elements in the vector since real elements are mixed with "holes", the logic is going to be obfuscated with additional checks.

Probably there is some sold reasoning behind the original design; unfortunately @user1535111 is not telling the details.

Comment: Exactly right! This design is problematic! I will come back to pointers. Nevertheless , this does not answer the asked problem, so I choose manlio's answer!